# What I'm doing wrong with await

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I am new, so it is something wrong. :-) I have this js code:

```
    onMount(async () => {
        pozoviRestServis(mojUrl, ucitajSve);
    }); 

    async function ucitajSve(data, mojUrl) {
        apiData.set(data);
    }
```

And in HTML I have lines to display:

```
{#await apiData}
    <p>wait</p>
{/await}
```

But, nothing happens?

Answer (score 3):

I assume `apiData` is a writable store. The correct syntax should be `{#await $apiData}`.

**Edit**:
I didn’t look closely. You did not use promise, so you shouldn’t use `#await`. Use `#if` instead.

```
{#if $apiData}
  <pre>{JSON.stringify($apiData)}</pre>
{/if}
```

If you want to work with promise, you need to modify your code accordingly

```
let setApiData;
let apiDataPromise = new Promise((resolve) => setApiData = resolve);

onMount(async () => {
    pozoviRestServis(mojUrl, ucitajSve);
}); 

async function ucitajSve(data, mojUrl) {
    setApiData(data);
}

{#await apiDataPromise}
    <span>wait</span>
{:then data}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>
{/await}
```

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you on your response. It help me a lot. So, in script I have:

```
    let apiDataPromise=ucitajSveJadanput();

    function ucitajSveJadanput() {
        **return** pozoviRestServis(mojUrl, ucitajSve);
    }

    /* onMount(async () => {
        pozoviRestServis(mojUrl, ucitajSve);
    }); */
```

In HTML I have it:

```
{#await apiDataPromise}
    <p>0</p>
{:then data} 
    <p>1</p>
{:catch e}
    <p>Error {e}</p>
{/await}
```

:-)